# Auto Populate from one cell to another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an amortization spreadsheet that calculates percentage remaining.  I want to click on a cell (A1) under the percentage column and auto populate on another worksheet "dashboard" (B1).  The next month, I want to click on the next cell (A2) in the amortization spreadsheet under the percentage column and populate in the dashboard worksheet in the same cell (B1).  Is this complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a formula to get the percent remaining from the last row in your (sorted) amortization schedule. Something like this:

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,COUNTA(Sheet1!B:B)),Sheet1!B:C,2,FALSE)
```